# Searching using custom properties on mysite

Tags: search, my-site, user-profile-property

I have a question about using a search to search on custom properties, properties that I've added myself to profile page.

So what I have now a user profile page with some standard properties like skills, interests etc and my own properties like hobby, music preference and sports.

I can search for them, when I search for 'Dance music' for example, I get an own profile, but the way it is beeing shown is not acceptable for me.
What I have now is this:
current = http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/nowrt.png/
but what I want to is to have like this:
how it should be= http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/803/howshouldbe.png/

So you see above like Skills: C# ... so like this I want to have.

You will prolly say adjust the XSLT .. that is what I have done I followed some tutorials on inet I just did exactly what they said, but I still don't have the result I want.
Here is the code that I put in XSLT (see comment for images for XSLT code)

So I did everything ... I can search for them it is ok ... working fine, but now I need it to be shown in a proper way. Just like with the standard properties.

And other things if you see the first 2 pictures you see that in summary all those properties are put next to each other without any space between them, how do I solve this too, so I put "," or just a space between them.

Comment: here are links for xslt: variables = http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/820/xsltvariables.png/
templates = http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/17/xslttemplate.png/

Comment: still no answer .. anyone able to help?

Comment: So, the first thing is to please not use the answer button to comment - I fixed that for you :-). Secondly you will improve the chance of getting a response if you post the images into the question - I think you have enough rep for that now. Don't forget that you can edit your question as much as you like, rather than having to use comments. Thanks.